# Backbone application organization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures, underscore.js

I organized my Backbone app as described at this page http://weblog.bocoup.com/organizing-your-backbone-js-application-with-modules

For those who hasn't read an article I'll explain the idea briefly:
I define single variable that will hold all of my modules.

```
var Application = {
  module: function(){
    var modules = {};
    return function(name){
      if (typeof modules[name] == 'undefined')
      {
        modules[name] = {
          Model: {},
          Collection: {},
          Views: {},
        }
      }
      return modules[name];
    };
  }()
};
```

Application.module is a function that will return module by name. Then I define my application modules as following:

```
(function(chat){
  chat.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... }),
  chat.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... }),
  etc.
})(Application.module('Chat'));
```

Everything seems to be ok - all the code is separated into modules, but when I am trying to instantiate a variable from one of the module's classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var foo = new Application.module('Chat').Collection();
});
```

Code above gives me Backbone's "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" error and I cannot understand why?

Answer (score 0):

i saw that error last week too... did you include underscore.js correctly?
in my case i had underscore.js included in the page, but after the backbone.js reference.

underscore.js really has to be loaded before backbone can do it's thing :)

do it like this:

```
<script src="underscore.min.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend strongly the use of [require][1]. 
It's very easy to implement and you can especify dependencies for all your .js librarys.

If you probe it once you can't will live without it.

Here you can see an example how it works:
https://github.com/charnekin/api/blob/master/js/main.js